# Eclipse libgdx import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I am following this tutorial http://steigert.blogspot.com/2012/02/3-libgdx-tutorial-scene2d.html and i get an error in eclipse for these imports:

`import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.OnActionCompleted;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Delay;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.FadeIn;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.FadeOut;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Sequence;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Align;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image.Scaling;`

all other libgdx imports work fine but these give me the import cannot be resolved error

does anyone of you know how to fix this?

Comment: What version of libgdx are you using? I suspect that you need to look at http://steigert.blogspot.com/2012/07/13-libgdx-tutorial-libgdx-refactoring.html to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I can see my code, yes - the libgdx version used in the steigert demos is not the latest, and lots of `scene2d` has changed since then.

http://steigert.blogspot.com/2012/07/13-libgdx-tutorial-libgdx-refactoring.html

You can get his refactored/updated code at:

https://code.google.com/p/steigert-libgdx/source/browse/tags/